# java thread periodically kills a process

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I have a java class that currently kicks off a a script via

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" run my script");
```

for specific reasons this pretty much runs all the time.  If the script dies for whatever reason the java class just starts it back up.

Now I'm needing to occasionally kill the process every so often.  So I decided to kick off a thread that would just sit and wait for a specific time, and then kill the process.  the java main class, or whatever, would still see the process die and then start it back up.

I don't know how to get this thread to see the process and the to subsequently kill it every so often.  Any suggestions on how to create that thread?  As a note, I haven't had to work with threads in a little while, so I'm a little rusty.

simple pseudo code of my class to get the basic idea of what I'm doing:

```
Class MyClass{

    Process mProc;

    main(args){
        do{
            try{
                mProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C myScript");
                mProc.destroy();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log(e);
            }
        } while(true);
```

Comment: Please avoid using pseudo code.  It's sloppy and can leave out important details (like what "r" is).

Comment: You could simply schedule a task to run when needed and call `myClass.mProc.destroy();`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Michael sorry, fixed the r.  it was supposed to be mProc.

Comment: This is essentially the code that runs.  I can fill it out by doing public void main  and the imports and such, but i saw no need. this is as clean and straightforward as I could get it.  I have something that happens between the .exec() call and the .destroy() but didn't believe them to be important since they weren't really related to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to get this thread to see the process and the to subsequently kill it every so often.

This is currently not easy to do as of Java 6.  The `Process` class has a `waitFor()` method but it does not take a timeout which is tragic given that internally it is just calling `wait()` -- at least in `UnixProcess`.

What you can do, which is somewhat of a hack is to synchronize on the `Process` and call `wait(timeoutMillis)` yourself.  Something like:

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder().command(commandArgs).start();
long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
synchronized (proc) {
    proc.wait(someTimeoutMillis);
}
long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis;
// if we get here without being interrupted and the delay time is more than
// someTimeoutMillis, then the process should still be running
if (diff >= someTimeoutMillis) {
   proc.destroy();
}
```

The issue is that there is a race condition and if the process finishes *before* you synchronize on `proc` you are going to wait for ever.  Another solution is to do your `proc.waitFor()` in one thread and then interrupt it in another thread once the timeout expires.

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder().command(commandArgs).start();
try {
   // this will be interrupted by another thread
   int errorCode = proc.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // always a good pattern to re-interrupt the thread
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   // our timeout must have expired so we need to kill the process
   proc.destroy();
}
// maybe stop the timeout thread here
```

Another option is to use the `proc.exitValue()` which allows you to test to see if the process executed.  Unfortunately instead of returning `-1` or something this throws `IllegalThreadStateException` if it has not finished.